# Datakeynames, request.querystring

Tags: asp.net

I am doing something wrong in this small code

Page1: `

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

       UserType = DDlUserType.SelectedItem.Text;
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           // Get the value in the hyperlink column.
           string HyperLinkValue = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
           HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink();

           myLink.NavigateUrl = "~/ShowMMBProfileStats1.aspx?Profile_ID={0}";
           myLink.Text = HyperLinkValue;
}
```

In ShowMMBProfileStats1.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        int MMBProfileID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[0]);

}
```

It gives me an error

> Input string was not in a correct
>   format.

In the aspx page, I am assigning `datakeynames="Profile_ID"`

How do I carry this `Profile_ID` to page1. 
               `
Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
myLink.NavigateUrl = 
    "~/ShowMMBProfileStats1.aspx?Profile_ID=" + e.Row.Cells[profileIDCellIndex].Text;
```

Comment: It is carrying "0". I need to get the ProfileID of the selected row in the grid to the next page

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I was  able to resolve the issue. Used datanavigateurl

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the value for `{0}`. Try something like this:

```
myLink.NavigateUrl = 
    String.Format("~/ShowMMBProfileStats1.aspx?Profile_ID={0}", HyperLinkValue );
```

or

```
 myLink.NavigateUrl = "~/ShowMMBProfileStats1.aspx?Profile_ID=" + HyperLinkValue ;
```